# How to delete the specific folder from the directory

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am developing one application. In that I have to delete the folder from the directory. I already have that folder path.

So how can I delete that folder from the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSError *error=nil;
BOOL isDeleted = [[NSFileManager defaulManager] removeItemAtPath:pathToYourFolder error:&error];
```